# dummy variable in Fourier transform confusion

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, integral-transforms

In this text, why is it using different dummy variable for the integral of coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$?
I know that choosing the dummy variable does not affect integral but over here since we are writing Fourier series of $f(x)$ choosing $t$ as dummy variable and $x$ in the series to represent the fourier series has led to expression $(15.17)$ which seems that he is considering $x$ and $t$ to be quite different?!
I know I am missing something important, but I am confused, please help me.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. The only dummy variable used in integration before $(15.17)$ is $t$. $n$ is used as the dummy variable in the summation, and it gets converted into the dummy variable $\omega$ in $(15.17)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** You may observe that, from $(15.14)$ to $(15.15)$ above, the author uses the classic identity
$$
\cos \frac{n\pi x}{L}\cos \frac{n\pi t}{L}+\sin \frac{n\pi x}{L}\sin \frac{n\pi t}{L}=\cos \frac{n\pi}{L}(t-x) \tag1
$$ then he makes use of a *Riemann sum* to obtain the final form
$$
f(x)=\frac 1\pi \int_0^{\infty}d\omega\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t) \cos (\omega(t-x))\: dt. \tag2
$$ In $(2)$, $t$ is **a dummy variable** and it is of course very different from the variable $x$, the latter being considered as **a parameter** for the integral.

Hoping this helps.

Comment: The question is, why $t$ is very different variable from $x$ , I see that some books use $x$ for both and they don't get that equation.

Comment: I'm trying to help you, but I'm not sure to understand your question. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, I think $x$ and $t$ should be the same, what if we had $x$ instead of $t$ as dummy variable.

Comment: If so, we would then have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t) \cos (\omega(t-x))\: dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t) \cos (\omega(x-x))\: dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t) \: dt$ which is not OK.

Comment: I know but why do we consider the dummy variable as the main input variable of the function in the Fourier series?! Probably, if you solve a problem with this formula everything is going to be clarified?!

Comment: OK, I think I guess your point! But it would be very difficult without speaking to you, without showing things with my fingers, to give a clearer explanation ... They did not take the dummy variable as the main variable, it is just an impression you have from reading $(15.14)$, but this is not so :)

Comment: If you have any other source which explains the point, it would be appreciated, I have got a problem between $t$ and $x$, here changing the dummy variable $t$ to $x$ can cause problems, but I have seen doing so in the Fourier series in which the dummy variable for calculating the coefficients is the same as main variable used for representing the series.

Comment: @FreeMind is your question simply about the choice of using dummy variables? Why we used t instead of x in line 5.12?
notice that 5.12 is a definite integral, and as such will equate to a scalar in the end. As a result, it didn't matter whether we used a t, a τ, a ♡ or whatever. Whichever symbol we use to integrate by, it will come out the same. In particular they chose to not use x so that they could come up with an expression for f(x) later on while using the work they did before.  As mentioned above, $t$ is being used as a parameter for the integral and $x$ as the variable for the function.

Comment: @JMoravitz I wish you could solve a problem with this formula in the form of an answer so I could fully get what you say. I know that dummy variable does not play any role in integration but over here it is tricky a little bit since it causes confusion!

Comment: Any answer? I am not satisfied with the answer that I already knew!

Comment: the thing is, the coefficient of Fourier series(a_n and b_n) are meant to be calculated first and then put in the series expression, and since we are combining them in order to get the equation 15.14, there is an order to solve the integral, that you can mess-up. And to push x(that is t now in 15.12 and 15.13) in the integral of f(x), the independence is shown by taking two variables.  That is the real answer to convince mathematics.